# MVC 3 Entity Framework Empty Result Set

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, epplus

I am working on an application in which it returns an excel report with each employee having multiple roles and their expected and actual hours for each role. For instance, I may be listed as a developer for one and a BA for another column!. The query it is using is returning an empty result set.

```
    public ActionResult ExpectedVsActual()
    {

        try
        {
            ProjectTotalsReportViewModel model = new ProjectTotalsReportViewModel();

            Employee currentUser = DataHelper.GetEmployee(User, db);

            model.AvailableEmployees = db.Employees.OrderBy(e => e.LastName).ThenBy(e => e.FirstName).ToList();

            if (currentUser.SecurityRoleCode == Constants.SECURITY_ROLE_CODE_ADMIN)
            {
                model.AvailableProjects = (db.Projects.Any() ? db.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectCategoryCode == Constants.PROJECT_CATEGORY_DIRECT).OrderBy(p => p.ProjectName).Distinct().ToList() : new List<Project>());

                model.ProjectRate = (db.EmployeeProjectRates.Any() ? db.EmployeeProjectRates.Where(epr => epr.EmployeeID == epr.EmployeeID).OrderBy(epr => epr.EmployeeID).Distinct().ToList(): new List<EmployeeProjectRate>());
            }
            else
            {
                model.AvailableProjects = (db.EmployeeProjectRates.Any(epr => epr.EmployeeID == currentUser.EmployeeID && epr.ProjectRoleCode == Constants.PROJECT_ROLE_PROJECT_MANAGER) ? db.EmployeeProjectRates.Where(epr => epr.EmployeeID == currentUser.EmployeeID && epr.ProjectRoleCode == Constants.PROJECT_ROLE_PROJECT_MANAGER).Select(epr => epr.Project).OrderBy(p => p.ProjectName).Distinct().ToList() : new List<Project>());
            }

            model.SelectedEmployeesForCheckBox = model.AvailableEmployees;
            model.SelectedProjectsForCheckBox = model.AvailableProjects;

            ViewBag.InitialLoad = true;

            return PartialView("_ExpectedVsActual", model);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }


[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExpectedVsActual(ProjectTotalsReportViewModel Model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                ViewBag.InitialLoad = false;
                DataHelper.TimeFrame selectedTimeFrame = DataHelper.TimeFrame.Weekly;//Need to remove after adding selection for time frame

                SMCContext db = new SMCContext();
                ViewBag.TimeFrameSelectList = DataHelper.GetTimeFrameSelectList();
                List<ProjectTimeFrame> timeFrames = new List<ProjectTimeFrame>();
                ProjectViewModel Project = new ProjectViewModel();
                timeFrames = DataHelper.GetProjectTimeFrames(Model.StartDate.Value, Model.EndDate.Value, selectedTimeFrame);

                Project.EmployeeProjectRates = Project.EmployeeProjectRates.OrderBy(epr => epr.Employees.Single(e => e.Value == epr.EmployeeID.ToString())).ToList();



                    resultFile = currentPackage.GetAsByteArray();
                    return File(resultFile, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Expected Vs Actual.xlsx");

                }
                #endregion
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("_ExpectedVsActual", Model);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;

        }







    }
```

The bulk of all the formatting and creation of the file I left out, it is not related to the empty result. The result should look like this
[image]

Comment: Have you tried enable the Sql Server Profiler and see the query that EF is sending to your DB?

Answer (score 1):

It's failing for you on at least one of three points:

1. Verify the data in your database reflects what you're searching for. The quickest way to do this is through some sort of profiler that can capture your EF query as it is transformed and show you the SQL statement. [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a great tool to do this with.
2. Verify your mappings. You might not have your relationships mapped correctly, producing no data to yield.
3. Verify your own constraints. It looks like you have permission-based lookups. Place a breakpoint after the current user is fetched and make sure it has the permission to match the permission you're looking for (`Constants.SECURITY_ROLE_CODE_ADMIN`) in your conditional.